# Run Python requests several times, but give different output

Tags: python, error-handling, python-requests

```
import requests

url = "https://www.eetimes.com/adi-and-marvell-enable-multi-antenna-radio-units-for-5g/"
try:
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
    r.raise_for_status()
except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError,requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects):
        print(url + "\nNOT ACCESSIBLE")
except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        print(url + "\n Time out")
else:
    print("Sucess!")
```

I don't know why I got different outputs running the same code. Sometimes I got "Time out", but sometimes I got "Success".
Does anyone encounter this problem before? Why does it happen in this way?

Thank you!

Comment: it's not a problem with the script but it's the server that is sending these different requests. the server is implemented such a way to avoid DOS attacks by bots.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the web site block you by "showing" you a wrong html code because they notice that it was a bot. You should add a header .